# Return to line one after using multiple lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know with end parameter I can write on one line side by side but couldn't figure out how after using multiple lines. I wonder if this is possible ?

The arithmetic function takes input as a list of strings that are arithmetic problems. For loop iterates over list input and slices operands and operators from list elements, applies operators to operands and prints out the whole arithmetic problem vertically with solution.  This is the code that I wrote :

```
import operator 

a = ["32 + 698", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"]


def arithmetic (l,default=None):
  
  ops = {
    '+' : operator.add,
    '-' : operator.sub}

  def compare (a,b):
    if len(a) > len(b):
      return len(a)
    else:
      return len(b)

  for i in l:
    argfinder = i.find(" ")
    a1 = i[0:argfinder]
    a2 = i[argfinder+3:]
    op = i[argfinder+1]
    out = str(ops.get(op)(int(a1),int(a2)))
    dash = "-"*(compare(a1,a2)+2)
    spaceout = " "*abs(len(dash) - len(str(out)))

    if default == True:

      if len(a1) <= len(a2):    
        spacea1 = " "*(abs(len(a1)-len(a2))+2)
        print(spacea1+a1, "\n"+op, a2,"\n"+dash+"\n"+spaceout+out)
      else:
        spacea1 = " "*(abs(len(dash)-compare(a1,a2)))
        spacea2 = " "*abs(len(a1)-len(a2))
        print(spacea1+a1+"\n"+op, spacea2+a2+"\n"+dash+"\n"+spaceout+out)
      

arithmetic(a,True)
```

Output:

```
   32 
+ 698 
-----
  730


  3801
-    2
------
  3799


  45 
+ 43 
----
  88


  123
+  49
-----
  172
```

I wonder if this output is possible:

```
   32      3801      45      123
+ 698    -    2    + 43    +  49
-----    ------    ----    -----
  730      3799      88      172
```

Comment: Can you think of code that would produce the string `32      3801      45      123` based on your input? How about `+ 698    -    2    + 43    +  49` and `730      3799      88      172`? Instead of trying to reposition the cursor, try to plan ahead and print the appropriate things in the appropriate order.

Comment: I thought that but I wonder if I can do any correction from here

Comment: What happened when you tried putting `python set terminal cursor position` into a search engine?

Comment: I don't know how to use them

Comment: @Karl Knechtel sorry couldn't realize that you wrote search engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know how to format a single operation, what you're having trouble with is
printing them side-by-side. So let's split your problem in two parts: first,
prepare the outputs for each operation separately, and in a second step, worry
about printing side-by-side.

The first step (which I'm not detailing here) should produce something like this:

```
operations = [
    ['   32', '+ 698', '-----', '  730'],
    ['  3801', '-    2', '------', '  3799'],
    ['  45', '+ 43', '----', '  88'],
    ['  123', '+  49', '-----', '  172'],
]
```

You already know how to do this, it's all there in your code, just fill in this
array instead of printing.

Now for the second part: you need to *transpose* the array, because you want all
the 1st arguments in one row, then all the 2nd arguments in the next row,
etc. You can use `zip` for that:

```
for arr in zip(*operations):
    print('   '.join(arr))
```

The expression `zip(*operations)` may seem like obscure magic if you're
unfamiliar with it, so let's explain that : the star operator `*` unpacks the
elements of `operation`, passing them as separate arguments to the `zip`
function.

`zip` does the actual transposition, putting all the 1st elements in one array,
then all the 2nd elements in another array, etc. Each of those arrays has what
you want to print in a row, so just iterate over them and print (after
including some separator whitespace wth `join`).

This produces the output you want:

```
   32     3801     45     123
+ 698   -    2   + 43   +  49
-----   ------   ----   -----
  730     3799     88     172
```

Comment: Actually last night I thought if I can iterate multiple indeces and with every index printing out an operation with zip but couldn't figure out how to do it. That's really helpful thanks.